# Navigating between 2 ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Im using `Navigation Controller` for my `ViewControllers`,I set my `importantViewController` as something like this to be its `RootView`:

```
UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: vc];
[self presentModalViewController: navControl animated: YES];
```

Then, I pushView anotherView the `FrontViewController` like this:

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

After a button is pressed in `FrontViewController` another view will be pushed `ViewA` but it is connected with another ViewController `ViewB` the same way as this AGAIN:

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

(Which I think Im doing wrong when dismissing either of them with `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`)

This is an illustration:

[image]

My problem is, I need to navigate between View A and View B then when I dismiss either of them it will got back to `FrontViewController`. Like a child of a child View. Thanks.

Comment: do you try [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; ?

Comment: I don't want to go back to `importantViewController` just `FrontViewController`

Comment: Are you trying to Push ViewA from ViewB?? if not please check my updated answer. If this is not you are looking for explain what issue you are facing

Comment: I want to navigate between them. View A -View B, View B - View A. something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is for **dismissModalViewController**, but try this,

From View B write code like this

```
[[self parentViewController].navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and From View A you can write,

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Or either you can use this,

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:frontViewController animated:YES];
```

**UPDATE**

```
for (UIViewController *tmpController  in [self.navigationController viewControllers]) 
{
    if ([tmpController isKindOfClass:[FrontViewController class]])
    {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:tmpController animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

This is the best solution to achieve this.

Write this code on both of your View A or B.

Hope it works now :-)

Comment: I want to navigate between View A then View B,  then when Im finish want to go back to `frontViewController` how to do this?

Comment: Yeah dear, Same thing I told you on both View A and View B, whenever you want to go back just write this code on button click.. Just try using this..

Comment: having problem with View A to View B then vice versa.

Comment: Whats problem you are facing you are facing?

Comment: No dear, Just Import it on your both View A and View B like #import "FrontViewController.h"

Comment: Still having issues with the imageView,buttons etc... from the otherView being stuck

Comment: No errors, but views are stuck like buttons, imageView from the other ViewController.

Comment: This code does not have any relations with ur Button or etc dear..Write this code on both of your back button of View A and View B..updated code only

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and patience sir XD

Answer (score 2):

There is one way @Prasad G indicated. But problem with this solution is you need the same object of `frontViewController`. You can't do this with creating a new object. For going to this way declare `frontViewController` object in appdelgate and while pushing it from importantVC use

```
appdelgate.frontViewController = // initialize
// Push it
```

While going back from view B

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:appdelegate.frontViewController animated:YES];
```

Another solution is

```
for (UIViewController *vc  in [self.navigationController viewControllers]) {
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[FrontViewController class]]) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

Using this way you can go on any of view controller from any level of navigation stack.

Using the first solution if you have 10 view Controllers and you want to go on any of one so you have to first create object of all 10 View Controller in appdelegate.

This code may have spell issues as I just typed this here

Hope this helps :)

**UPDATE**

->You have impVC as your root view
-> You pushed frontVC
-> From there you Pushed VC_A
-> From there you want to push VC_B

so you are done with pushing and for coming back to VC_A you can use

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated];
```

Now you can again come on VC_B and again pop it. For going to frontVC from VC_A you can use `popViewControllerAnimated` and for going to frontVC from VC_B you can use the for loop i mentioned.

Please explain if you are looking anything else. If you are still facing issue please explain.

Comment: I want to navigate between View A then View B,then VICE VERSA, then when Im finish and want to go back, it will go back to `frontViewController` on button pressed, how to do this?

Comment: for view A and than View B you can push view B from A and for coming back to view A use Pop. Or you don't want to pop?

Comment: so I follow you're steps, it was right unto View A to View B, but when View B to A the View is stuck then when want to go back to FrontView it go backs to View A.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:frontViewController animated:YES];
```

Try like this i think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

In FrontViewController After a button is pressed:

```
  ViewA instance
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:ViewA animated:YES]
```

When ViewA disissmed

```
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Load  ViewB in ViewA

```
  ViewB instance
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:ViewB animated:YES]
```

On back viewB to FrontViewController

```
 FrontViewController instance
[self.navigationController popToViewController:FrontViewController animated:YES];
```

On back viewB to viewA

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```